# NotebookDirectory in NotebookEvaluate

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, files-and-directories

Suppose Notebook A calls NotebookEvaluate[Notebook B]. Notebook B calls NotebookDirectory[]. Naturally, NotebookDirectory[] returns the directory of Notebook B.  Is there an option to have NotebookDirectory[] return the directory of Notebook A?

Comment: If you select Notebook A before evaluating `NotebookEvaluate[Notebook B]`, then you can get the directory of Notebook A in Notebook B by `dirA = 
 NotebookDirectory[SelectedNotebook[]]`, but I would not really do this at all. Just use .m or .wl files and `DirectoryName[$InputFileName]`. Extended programming should not be done in notebooks, I think.